# How can I dynamcially use a parameter as an operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, parameters

I want to either add or subtract

so I pass in 'action' as a paramater

How do I do `a 'action' b` for `a+b` or `a-b`

I tried eval but no luck, `undefined method 'action'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `send`.

```
action = "+"
a.send(action, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Eval works for me.

```
2.0.0p247 :006 > action = '+'
 => "+"
2.0.0p247 :007 > eval("5 #{action} 2")
 => 7
```

Comment: `eval` works, but in my opinion, it should really be reserved for cases in which plain ol' ruby truly can't do what you need (i.e., you need a really *really* good reason to use `eval`), primarily you'll run into lots of security and debugging issues. In this case, `send` works just as well, and should be preferred.